# Converting Dataframe into an array of 3D shape

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, conv-neural-network, reshape

My `X_train` is 693x148 where values are arrays of 300 time points, so a shape of (300,).

[image: Here is an image of .xlsx]

I want to create a numpy array of my dataset and reshape it like (693,148,300), to feed it to my CNN.

Any ideas ?

I've tried

```
X_train = np.array(X_train).reshape(693,148,300)
```

but I get :

> "cannot reshape array of size 102564 into shape (693,148,300)"*

Comment: Take a look at [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

Answer (score 1):

Update :

I tried this and it works :
`X_train = np.array(X_train.T.values.tolist())`

For those who need.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when training LSTM NN. I found this function somewhere, and it worked. Sorry that I can not provide a proper step-by-step, but first transform your X_train to np.array and consider this function:

```
def createXY(dataset, n_past):
    dataX = []

    for i in range(n_past, len(dataset)):
        dataX.append(dataset[i - n_past:i, 0:dataset.shape[1]])

return np.array(dataX)
```

Try it with n_past=1. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i've try your function with n_past = 1 and my np.array(X_train) and i get a shape of (692,1,148). Not exacly what i wanted and it appears that i missing one elem of my 693 experience subject.